# Filter dataframe in R on occurrence of multiple patterns in a string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, filter

**Data**

I have a data frame with a single column consisting of strings in R.

```
data <- structure(list(col = c("byr:1985 eyr:2021 iyr:2011 hgt:175cm pid:163069444 hcl:#18171d", 
                       "eyr:2023 hcl:#cfa07d ecl:blu hgt:169cm pid:494407412 byr:1936", 
                       "ecl:zzz eyr:2036 hgt:109 hcl:#623a2f iyr:1997 byr:2029 cid:169 pid:170290956", 
                       "hcl:#18171d ecl:oth pid:266824158 hgt:168cm byr:1992 eyr:2021", 
                       "byr:1932 ecl:hzl pid:284313291 iyr:2017 hcl:#efcc98 eyr:2024 hgt:184cm"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**Problem**

I want to filter this data frame on the rows that contain the following patterns/fields:

```
fields <- c("ecl", "eyr", "hgt", "hcl", "iyr", "byr", "pid")
```

In other words, I would like to obtain the rows that *do* contain each of these fields.

**Attempt**

The `stringr` package and `str_detect` function seemed to be the solution! So, I tested it on a single case:

```
> data$col[1]
[1] "byr:1985 eyr:2021 iyr:2011 hgt:175cm pid:163069444 hcl:#18171d"
> str_detect(data$col[1], fields)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> all(str_detect(data$col[1], fields))
[1] FALSE
```

This works! If any of the fields are not present in the string, it is evaluated as false.

However, when trying to filter the rows using this option:

```
data %>% 
    filter( all(str_detect(col, fields)) )
```

I end up with an empty data frame, and a warning:

> Warning message: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate =
> negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :   longer object length is not a
> multiple of shorter object length

**Question(s)**

- What is causing this warning?
- How do you filter a column of strings on the occurrence of multiple patterns in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get the warning is because `str_detect` is vectorised function meaning 1st value in `col` is matched with 1st value of `fields`, 2nd value with the 2nd and so on. Length of `col` is 5 and length of `fields` is 7 so their lengths are incompatible and that is what the warning is saying.

To filter the rows in `data` where each value of `fields` is present in base R, you could do :

```
data[Reduce(`&`, lapply(fields, grepl, data$col)), ]

#  col                                                                         
#  <chr>                                                                       
#1 ecl:zzz eyr:2036 hgt:109 hcl:#623a2f iyr:1997 byr:2029 cid:169 pid:170290956
#2 byr:1932 ecl:hzl pid:284313291 iyr:2017 hcl:#efcc98 eyr:2024 hgt:184cm
```

---

If you are interested in `tidyverse` answer you could write the above as :

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% filter(map(fields, ~str_detect(data$col, .x)) %>% reduce(`&`))
```